# In C, why swapping x with y is faster then swapping y with x?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, swap

In a problem [minimum-swaps-2](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-swaps-2) ,  arr is unsorted array, arr_count is number of array elements, we need to return minimum number of swaps to sort the array,

i tried:

```
int minimumSwaps(int arr_count, int* arr) {
    int swap = 0;
    for(int i  = 0; i < arr_count;){
        if(arr[i] != (i + 1)){
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[arr[i] - 1];
            arr[arr[i] - 1] = temp;
            swap++;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return swap;
}
```

but it didn't work. It shows time out error. i.e. it took more time to run!
Then i tried the below code, it worked!

```
        int temp = arr[arr[i] - 1];
        arr[arr[i] - 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        swap++;
```

The only difference between both is swapping x with y or y with x. What difference does it make?

Comment: What is `i`? What is `arr`?  Please make a [mre]

Comment: @OcasoProtal there is actually enough information here, this code works alike with any legal values

Comment: arr[arr[i] - 1]; looks incorrect to me. Shouldn't it be something like arr[i - 1];

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, I know, but that is bad question style. And since the OP is first time user it is always better to ask for an MRE. That was just a frinedly hint, I didn't dv or cv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `arr[i] = arr[arr[i] - 1];` the value `arr[i]` was changed and  `arr[arr[i] - 1]` doesn't point at same storage anymore, `arr[arr[i] - 1] = temp;` writes to wrong storage.

So you actually do not swap two values. It could be obvious if you represented it as pointer arithmetic.

```
        int temp = *(arr + i);
        *(arr + i) = *(arr + temp - 1);
        *(arr + *(arr + i) - 1) = temp;
```

Last line equals to  `*(arr + *(arr + temp - 1) - 1)` with values present at moment before line 2 execution, which IS wrong by definition of task.

In fact it gives obvious solution:

```
        int temp = *(arr + i);
        *(arr + i) = *(arr + temp - 1);
        *(arr + temp - 1) = temp;
```

or

```
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[temp - 1];
        arr[temp - 1] = temp;
```

Which yields result of 5 returned from `minimumSwaps`.

Essentially you time-outed because first variant unable to reach solution.

Comment: If the values in the array have 9-digit numbers, the original will crash quicker. I suspect the testing data has some permutation of 0..N-1 where N is the size of the array.

Comment: that addition + dereference syntax hurts eyes... why'd you use that if the question didn't?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it's for explanation of code below. And OP was confused by brevity of []  syntax.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler original was infinite loop with any legal data given by test, is  unique values `1<= arr[i] <=N` for array of size N. But you're right, that challenge  once had erroneous data test (a typo , 8 instead of 7)